# ActiveMq could not access queue web page

Tags: queue, activemq-classic

My english is not good. But I meet a problem when I visit activemq queue page. 
    When I visit the http://MY-IP:8161/admin/queues.jsp And web Page return me : 
Error!

Exception occurred while processing this request, check the log for more information!

And After I look the log backend, And it shows :

```
 2017-11-02 08:26:05,892 | WARN  |  | org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | qtp801028830-289
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 59 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.tooltip_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 59 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.tooltip_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 71 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.escape_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 71 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.escape_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.escape_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.escape_tag cannot be resolved to a type


    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)[geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.JspPropertyGroupServlet.service(JspPropertyGroupServlet.java:132)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)[activemq-web-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:102)[file:/opt/apache-activemq-5.11.1/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/classes/:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_25]
2017-11-02 08:26:05,898 | WARN  | /admin/queues.jsp | org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | qtp801028830-289
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 59 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.tooltip_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 59 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.tooltip_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 71 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.escape_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 71 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.escape_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.escape_tag cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /queues.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.escape_tag cannot be resolved to a type


    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)[geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.JspPropertyGroupServlet.service(JspPropertyGroupServlet.java:132)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)[activemq-web-5.11.1.jar:5.11.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:102)[file:/opt/apache-activemq-5.11.1/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/classes/:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[jetty-all-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_25]
```

And The queues.jsp code like below:

```
<%--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
--%>
<html>
<head>
<c:set var="pageTitle" value="Queues"/>

<%@include file="decorators/head.jsp" %>
</head>
<body>

<%@include file="decorators/header.jsp" %>

<div>
<form action="createDestination.action" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="JMSDestinationType" value="queue"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="<c:out value='${sessionScope["secret"]}'/>"/>

    <label name="destination">Queue Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="JMSDestination" value=""/>

    <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
</div>


<h2>Queues</h2>

<table id="queues" class="sortable autostripe">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Number Of Pending Messages</th>
<th>Number Of Consumers</th>
<th>Messages Enqueued</th>
<th>Messages Dequeued</th>
<th>Views</th>
<th>Operations</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${requestContext.brokerQuery.queues}" var="row">

<tr>
<td><a href="<c:url value="browse.jsp">
                        <c:param name="JMSDestination" value="${row.name}" /></c:url>"><form:tooltip text="${row.name}" length="50"/></a></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.queueSize}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.consumerCount}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.enqueueCount}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.dequeueCount}" /></td>
<td>
    <a href="<c:url value="browse.jsp">
                   <c:param name="JMSDestination" value="${row.name}" /></c:url>">Browse</a>
    <a href="<c:url value="queueConsumers.jsp">
                    <c:param name="JMSDestination" value="${row.name}" /></c:url>">Active Consumers</a><br/>
    <a href="<c:url value="queueProducers.jsp">
                    <c:param name="JMSDestination" value="${row.name}" /></c:url>">Active Producers</a><br/>
    <a href="queueBrowse/<form:escape text="${row.name}" />?view=rss&feedType=atom_1.0" title="Atom 1.0"><img src="images/feed_atom.png"/></a>
    <a href="queueBrowse/<form:escape text="${row.name}" />?view=rss&feedType=rss_2.0" title="RSS 2.0"><img src="images/feed_rss.png"/></a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="<c:url value="send.jsp">
                    <c:param name="JMSDestination" value="${row.name}" />
                    <c:param name="JMSDestinationType" value="queue"/></c:url>">Send To</a>
    <a href="<c:url value="purgeDestination.action">
                    <c:param name="JMSDestination" value="${row.name}" />
                    <c:param name="JMSDestinationType" value="queue"   />
                    <c:param name="secret" value='${sessionScope["secret"]}'/></c:url>">Purge</a>
    <a href="<c:url value="deleteDestination.action">
                    <c:param name="JMSDestination" value="${row.name}" />
                    <c:param name="JMSDestinationType" value="queue"   />
                    <c:param name="secret" value='${sessionScope["secret"]}'/></c:url>">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>

<%@include file="decorators/footer.jsp" %>

</body>
</html>
```

Environment:

- activemq 5.11.1
- jdk 1.8.0_25
- linux

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that you are using an ActiveMQ version that was not built for and did not support running on JDK 8.  If you update to 5.15.2 or run on JDK 7 then this should work.  This error is commonly seen from those web console dependencies when running on newer JDKs.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. And I will update my activemq version. and have a try.

Comment: Thanks. I had JDK 8 and activemq 5.9.0 having the same issue. Now, upgraded to activemq 5.15.0 and i can view the messages now.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of different JDK version.

I added that path to the activemq.bat file in the activemq-versionxxx\bin directory, so it uses that version instead of the JAVA_HOME version.

This the location in .bat file:

```
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto noJavaHome 

if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome 

if "%_JAVACMD%" == "" set _JAVACMD=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\java.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You may click on Atom to view the messages in the queue, if you do not want to restart ActiveMQ:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem for activemq 5.10 on **windows** machine. 
Use java 1.6 to start the app solved my problem.